# How to retrieve the position of a list in a list of lists in python

Tags: python

```
A = [['0', '6', '4', '3'], ['0', '2', '8', '3'], ['0', '4', '1', '5'], ['0', '3', '2', '5']]
B = ['0', '4', '1', '5']
```

Say I want to find out at which line does B equal to the list. How do I write a solution for this?

The answer would be the third line.

I tried doing a for loop.

Comment: “Line”‽ Do you mean which element in `A` equals `B`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `list.index(element)` to get the index of the element in the original list (`A`). In your terminology, to get the *line* just add one to the index.

```
line = A.index(B) + 1
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need use loops.you can get the element index by indexing.

```
A = [['0', '6', '4', '3'], ['0', '2', '8', '3'], ['0', '4', '1', '5'], ['0', '3', '2', '5']]

B = ['0', '4', '1', '5']

print(A.index(B))

>>> 2
```

Comment: This one worked as well. Thanks.